# $.ajaxSend, $.ajaxComplete, Rails UJS and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jquery

I have ajaxified links in my rails project:

```
<%= link_to 'Click me!', some_url, remote: true %>
```

I added hooks to listen for ajax events:

```
$(function(){
  $(document).ajaxSend( function(){$('#busy').show()} )
  $(document).ajaxComplete( function(){$('#busy').hide()} )
})
```

This works as expected in FF.

In Chrome, the `#busy` div appears as expected when an ajax request is sent, but when the request arrives Chrome goes blank and the console shows a long javascript error message:

```
jQuery.event.dispatch
elemData.handle.eventHandle
jQuery.event.trigger
(anonymous function)
jQuery.extend.each
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each
jQuery.fn.extend.trigger
... (several hundred lines of pretty much the same stuff)
```

Why is Chrome barfing on what appears to be a simple addition of an event handler?

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer your question directly, but the rails way to handle ajax events is captured nicely on this page: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax

It may have to do with the way the events are being passed upwards.

```
<%= link_to 'Click me!', some_url, remote: true, id: 'clickable' %>

$('#clickable').on('ajax:beforeSend', function(event, xhr, settings) {
  $('#busy').show()
});

$('#clickable').on('ajax:complete', function(event, xhr, settings) {
  $('#busy').hide()
});
```